# Constant function pointer optimization

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, optimization, function-pointers

I am trying to implement an abstract interface in C using function pointers inside a struct.
Something like the following

```
typedef int (*fn_t)(int);
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    const fn_t fnp;
}struct_t;

__attribute__((optimize("O0"))) int square(int num) 
{
    return num * num;
}

static struct_t test = {.fnp = square};

int main(void)
{
    test.x = 1;

    int fnp_ret = test.fnp(3);

    return (fnp_ret);
}
```

When building in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GzoExrf4K) with -O3 using ARM-GCC-13.2.0 unknown-eabi the output is the following.

```
square:
        str     fp, [sp, #-4]!
        add     fp, sp, #0
        sub     sp, sp, #12
        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
        mov     r2, r3
        mul     r2, r3, r2
        mov     r3, r2
        mov     r0, r3
        add     sp, fp, #0
        ldr     fp, [sp], #4
        bx      lr
main:
        mov     r1, #1
        ldr     r3, .L5
        mov     r0, #3
        ldr     r2, [r3, #4]
        str     r1, [r3]
        bx      r2
.L5:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
```

Here one can see that in `main()` the assembly emitted, first locates the function pointer in the struct and then de-references it. I find this strange since the function pointer is `const` so I expected that the compiler should figure out that it always points to the `square` function so it would be equivalent to calling the `square` function directly. Apparently this is not the case here.

During experiment I noticed that in case the statement `test.x = 1;` is commented out, the assembly does what I expected, by calling the `square` function directly

```
square:
        str     fp, [sp, #-4]!
        add     fp, sp, #0
        sub     sp, sp, #12
        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
        mov     r2, r3
        mul     r2, r3, r2
        mov     r3, r2
        mov     r0, r3
        add     sp, fp, #0
        ldr     fp, [sp], #4
        bx      lr
main:
        mov     r0, #3
        b       square
```

What am I missing?
Is there any way to implement this reliably without paying the performance hit described above?

Comment: You care about performance but function is definitely not optimal

Comment: @gulpr: The function is a placeholder for the demonstration. Its optimization or lack thereof is irrelevant for the demonstration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think OP wanted `noinline`

Comment: This may be specific to the arm compiler/optimizer. When I build your _first_ example for x86, under `gcc` (8.3.1) `main` is three lines: `movl $1, test(%rip); movl $3, %edi; jmp *test+8(%rip);` This is what your _second_ test does (but doesn't "inline" the function pointer). But, under `clang` (7.0.1), it is: `movl $9, %eax; retq;` So, this may be "premature optimization". (i.e. Don't worry--be happy!). You're _only_ saving _one_ `ldr` instruction. What might be more interesting is to _loop_ on the call and see if the address is cached in a register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. optimize O0 is not the right one. You want `noinline`
2. It is well known gcc optimizer flaw. If you touch any member of the struct it considers the whole struct as non `const`

```
__attribute__((noinline)) int square(int num) 
{
    return num * num;
}
```

> What am I missing? Is there any way to implement this reliably without
> paying the performance hit described above?

You can't do anything about it, I am afraid. Most likely it will never be sorted. if it matters to you you can use clang: https://godbolt.org/z/T4bznYE4h

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Indeed avoiding inlining was my intention for the attribute so thank you for that too. Regarding the  GCC optimizer flow could you give me some leads to research it further? Probably some issue link or keywords. Thanks again

Comment: @user3387106: Depending on what you want to prevent, you might need `__attribute__((noinline,noipa))` to completely prevent any inter-procedural analysis (like that the function is pure so the call can still be skipped if the return value isn't used, or making a custom calling convention, like the caller taking advantage of the fact that the function happens not to clobber a register that in the ABI normally is call-clobbered.)  The `noclone` attribute can be relevant for not letting GCC invent a version of a function  with one or more args constant-propagated, but `noipa` covers that.